# strange dis.dis behavior in python 2

Tags: python-2.7

I found a weird bug in `dis.dis()` from Python 2.7.14 when passing strings:

```
>>> dis.dis("import dis")
          0 BUILD_MAP       28781
          3 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP 29810
          6 SLICE+2
          7 LOAD_CONST      29545 (29545)
>>> dis.dis("import os")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dis.py", line 45, in dis
    disassemble_string(x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dis.py", line 112, in disassemble_string
    labels = findlabels(code)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dis.py", line 166, in findlabels
    oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I figured out that it works if and only if the length of the module name is divisible by 3, after testing several other modules. In Python 3.7, everything works fine (tested with the online shell from [python.org](https://www.python.org))

Comment: Same bug exists in Python 2.7.16.